# How can git differentiate deltified pack record types?

Tags: git

In a pack file there are records, which according to [this](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles) post have the type stored in the header, along with some other metadata.

Looking at the [JGit source](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/8a6af368c4129ef35520ec72cc9f55a3f685bfb8/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Constants.java#L139) I can see the following values.

- 0 - EXTENDED
- 1 - COMMIT
- 2 - TREE
- 3 - BLOB
- 4 - TAG
- 5 - RESERVED
- 6 - OFS_DELTA
- 7 - REF_DELTA

However, if the object is deltified then the type in the header will be set to 6 or 7, and after that there seems to be no added header showing the type of the payload, just some method of getting the original and then the delta data.

How can git tell the type of a deltified pack record, so that it doesn't mix up types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, Git does not store deltas of objects of different types. You can find confirmation of this in lengthy description/discussion provided with Git source code in file `Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt`.

> <gitster> (…) What this means is:
>
> - we do not delta different object types.
> - (…  )

Therefore it follows, that you can infer object type either from:

- REF_DELTA: object referenced by first 20-bytes of pack file entry
- OFS_DELTA: object occupying position earlier in a pack (more details in `Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt`)